# Why doesn't struct exist after declaration inside of function?

Tags: c, struct

I've tried a lot of simple examples of this and haven't gotten any to work.

My goal is to have a function which declares a struct internally, sets the values of the struct, and then returns the struct.

```
struct getData(void){
    typedef struct{
        int count1;
        int count2;
    } MyStruct;

    MyStruct myData;

    myData.count1 = 5;
    myData.count2 = 6;

    return myData;
};

int main(void) {
    struct myData = getData()

    printf("count1: %i", myData.count1);
    printf("count2: %i", myData.count2);
}
```

Every example I've found does something similar to this, but for some reason it's not finding my struct called MyStruct.  Exact error is:

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘void’
 struct getData(void){
                ^~~~
```

The error I keep getting makes me think it doesn't like the struct inside the function.

Comment: Define "similar". :O Your code is very far from standard C.

Comment: The keyword `struct` needs to be followed by either the name of a previously declared structure type, or the specification of the sdtructure. You can't just declare a variable or function as returning an unknown type of structure.

Comment: If you want to use a struct outside the function its definition must be visible there. Therefore you can't define it inside the function. You can define a variable of this struct type inside the function and return it, though.

Comment: The curly brackets represent scope of visibility of symbols. So you can't expect something declared in an inner scope (the function) to be visible on the outside.

Comment: With the struct type defined local within `getData` what form of magic do you expect to use *outside* the function to access the members set within? Amore fundamental question: What are you *really* trying to accomplish? I ask because this seems very much an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you have a problem, decided firmly on a solution, tried the solution, and upon failing, decided the problem is within your solution; not the original problem itself. So.. what are you *really* trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @WhozCraig I was originally trying to accomplish creating a function which takes in a file, and then returns two values (not pointers passed in).  The two values were going to be an array of lines from the file, and the count of lines from the file.  I got all of it working in a single main(), but when I tried breaking the logic into functions, I failed.  So you're probably right that it is an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be a confusion regarding the usage of the `struct` keyword. You don't do `struct myData` to declare a variable named `myData` that is of `struct` type, because there isn't really a `struct` type. What you do is `struct myData <SOMETHING>` to define `<SOMETHING>` as being a new data type named `struct myData`. You can then say `struct myData dat;`, thereby declaring that `dat` is a variable of type `struct myData`.

You're also demonstrating the same confusion at the top, where you have `struct getData(void)`... you're attempting to declare `getData` as a function returning a struct, but you'd really have to do something like `struct myData getData(void)` to declare a function returning type `struct myData`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more standard way to write what you're after is this, using an independent definition of the struct, and then using a pointer for the function call. As written your code seems to have some scope issues (declaring a struct typedef inside a function, hmmm...) [Incorrect->] plus I don't believe structs can be passed around that way in C, I'm pretty sure you have to use pointers. [Edit oops this is incorrect! See comments]

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    } MyStruct;

void getData (MyStruct* myDataPtr) {
    myDataPtr->count1 = 5;    //note pointer access notation ->
    myDataPtr->count2 = 6;
};

int main(void) {
    MyStruct myData;
    MyStruct* sPtr = &myData;  //create pointer to struct, assign to myDaya
    getData(sPtr);            //pass pointer to function
    printf("count1: %i \n", myData.count1);
    printf("count2: %i \n", myData.count2);
}
```

Outputs:

```
count1: 5
count2: 6
```

Comment: *"I don't believe structs can be passed around that way in C"* - you're wrong. They can be passed around by value without issue. `MyStruct getData()` is completely viable, and in fact one common technique for returning an array by value from a function (i.e. bury it in a structure type).

Comment: structs can be passed just fine.  Only issue is that if it's really big then that there could be a lot of data being copied.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea for some reason... can you do that in C++ too? And you can bury an array in a struct and pass it about, too... I wonder if the scope issue is a problem then?

Comment: You can also bury an array in a struct and assign one of those things to another to get around the lack of array assignment. It fills your code up of long-winded and ugly constructs, but every once in a while it's worth it. (And given the *extreamely* long-winded nature of some of the c++ code I'm producing thiese days `aryStruct.ary[i]` doesn't seem so bad anymore.)